# Save a loyalty card to Android Pay

Tags: android, android-pay

I want to save an existing loyalty card from my app to Android Pay.

When creating the LoyaltyWalletObject:

```
 LoyaltyWalletObject wob = LoyaltyWalletObject.newBuilder()
                .setClassId(ISSUER_ID +"." + LOYALTY_CLASS_ID)
                .setId(ISSUER_ID +"." + LOYALTY_OBJECT_ID)
                .setState(WalletObjectsConstants.State.ACTIVE)
                .setAccountId(userPreferences.getAccountId())
                .setIssuerName("Baconrista")
                .setProgramName("Baconrista Rewards")
                .build();
```

I have to pass in the ISSUER_ID, LOYALTY_CLASS_ID and LOYALTY_OBJECT_ID. How can I obtain these values? From where can I obtain them?

I did read the Android Pay doc. I find it very confusing. I only want to save the loyalty card to Android Pay. I don t want to use payment transactions..and so on. Thx

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out? I have similar questions regarding this.

Comment: Hey i am facing same issue, did you figure it out? if yes could please help me to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
LoyaltyWalletObject wob = LoyaltyWalletObject.newBuilder()
                .setClassId("2967745143867465930" +"." + "01_LoyaltyClass")
                .setId("2967745143867465930" +"." + "01_LoyaltyObjectId_11")
                .setState(WalletObjectsConstants.State.ACTIVE)
                .setAccountId(userPreferences.getAccountId())
                .setIssuerName("Baconrista")
                .setProgramName("Baconrista Rewards")
                .build();
```

I guess you are referring their github code.Those values they have stored in the values.xml file.To know how to pass those values refer:https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/guides/loyalty/get-started-android[image]

Refer the documentation carefully:https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/guides/loyalty/get-started-android.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thx for your reply. I did read this. I don t understand what is Android Pay Merchant Console? Do I need to use it in order to obtain a LOYALTY_CLASS_ID and a LOYALTY_OBJECT_ID?